# char[] to String Conversion in Spring configuration

Tags: spring

I have bean A that returns an attribute as char[] and another bean that expects an attribute as String and I would like to inject the attribute from bean A to bean B.

When I do this:

```
    <bean id="B" class="....">
        <property name="password" value="#{A.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="A" class="...">
    </bean>
```

The error I'm getting is:

**Cannot convert value of type [char[]] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'password': no matching editors or conversion strategy found**

Any idea how to resolve this?

Perhaps by using an expression language syntax?

Perhaps by registering some sort of a converter like org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CharArrayPropertyEditor in the configuration before injecting the char[] attribute?

Comment: What about `"#{new java.lang.String(A.password)}"`?

Comment: uhmm didn't think of that I must admit and it seems to be working.
If you reply to my question properly and not as a comment then I'm happy to accept this as a solution and reward you with points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this will work:

```
<property name="password" value="#{new java.lang.String(A.password)}" />
```